# Donate at end of game

Tags: dominion, dominion-empires

I was just playing Dominion online, and I planned to Donate my curses at end of game.

The card says:

> After this turn, put all cards from your deck and discard pile into your hand, trash any number, shuffle your hand into your deck, then draw 5 cards.*

Since I had two buys, I used one to buy the last province, then the second one to buy donate. Yet, the game ended, without giving me the option to trash the two curses from my deck.

Is this a bug in the Dominion server implementation, or am I missing a fine print somewhere?

To me, the wording is pretty clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The game designer intends that "after this turn" effects do not happen when the game ends. The game ends **at the end of your turn**, so any other effects set up after that can't happen: nothing happens after the game ends. Likewise if you have five Possession effects stacked up for "after this turn" but the game ends, you of course do not play those turns.

References:

- [shuffle.it forums](http://forum.shuffleit.nl/index.php?PHPSESSID=0b2aaf85f0c46b288ed83c0986780aa6&topic=2765.0;wap2)
- [Wiki](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Donate#Other_rules_clarifications)

Comment: > If sufficient piles to end the game are emptied during Donate's effect (such as by trashing Hunting Grounds or Catacombs), the next player takes their turn and then you check if the game still ends.

Woah.... Mindblown. But, OK, settled.

Comment: This rule changed. "Donate will be receiving errata to happen at the end of your turn, instead of in-between turns. Here is a list of rulings that will change as a result." http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Donate